# How do you restrict access to Azure Web App by incoming header value?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-front-door

I'm trying to lock down access to my Azure Web App by following the instructions here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#how-do-i-lock-down-the-access-to-my-backend-to-only-azure-front-door.

The first step I did through the Azure Portal but I'm unsure as to where to do the second step (filter on the values for the incoming header 'X-Forwarded-Host'). Is it through the portal? or through Host Filtering in the app itself? or through a WAF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since March 2020, Azure Frontdoor sends a `X-Azure-FDID` header with a unique value of your Frontdoor instance.

I wrote a detailed blog post about how to utilize that in restricting access to your web app: https://henrihietala.fi/limit-access-to-your-azure-web-app-from-your-azure-front-door-only/

Comment: Here is direct link for the info on MS release for the March 2020 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-front-door-march-2020-updates/  -
Check out bullet "Easier lockdown for backends"

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just adding some middleware to do this:

```
    public class XForwardedHostMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public XForwardedHostMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {            
                var forwardedHost = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"].ToString();

                if (forwardedHost != "ex.ample.com")
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Blocked");
                }
                else
                {
                    await _next(context);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well App service it self does not provide any service on restricting access on bases of header values. App service can only filter traffic on IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As the providing [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#how-do-i-lock-down-the-access-to-my-backend-to-only-azure-front-door), the incoming header **X-Forwarded-Host** was sent by Front Door. Front Door Service includes headers from an incoming request unless removed because of restrictions. Front Door also adds the following headers:

[image]

Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http-headers-protocol).

Comment: I understand that it is setting this header - the question is how to restrict access from any request that doesn't contain the correct value in this header.

Comment: [Here](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/using-azure-front-door-with-dotnet-core) is a reference for using Azure Front Door with .NET Core. Since `Azure Front Door Service supports the X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Host, and X-Forwarded-Proto headers. For X-Forwarded-Host and X-Forwarded-Proto, the value is overridden. `So you only could restrict access via host filtering on your backend as only the backend will receive this X-Forwarded-Host header and the front door just adds the X-Forwarded-Host header as my reply.